# MoveByCrane: Move agent by crane to another agent

Tags: anylogic

I have a problem with the MoveByCrane block.

I want that a crane moves an agent (container) to another agent (truck). Both are two types of agents.

In the MoveByCrane block exits the option to choose "Destination is" to "Agent". My idea was to tell the crane here: Move the container to the truck.

Each Container has a variable named v_ExitTruck in which I save a specific truck. This truck is the destination where the container should be move to by the crane.

So, in the MoveByCrane block I've choosen the option "Destination is: Agent" and then I specified the agent with the variable I saved for each container: "agent.v_ExitTruck. In the image you can see the settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBnPt.png

But, now I get the error that this variable "cannot be resolved or is not a field".

I really don't know what I did wrong here.

I hope some of you can help me out here :) Thaanks1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force-tell the field that `agent` will be a `Container` using type-casting:

`((Container)agent).v_ExitTruck` should work (if your `Container` actually has a `v_ExitTruck`!)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works.
But why is it needed in this case to force-tell the field that agent will be a Container?

Comment: Because you might want to move this to any Agent type in your model, not just the actual agent type flowing through. So the devs give you maximum flexibility here :)